# Laravel - Get value of a simple array made json through json_extract and eloquent select

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent, json-extract

I am trying to get the value of an array made json in Laravel through [unquoting extraction operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) but it doesn't work.

Json in database

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Eloquent

```php
->select('data->[2] as data')
```

SQL generated for laravel

```sql
"select json_unquote(json_extract(`data`, '$."[2]"')) as `data` from `table`"
```

when should it be like this:

```sql
"select json_unquote(json_extract(`data`, '$[2]')) as `data` from `table`"
```

**How should I create the 'select' in eloquent for when the json is a simple array???**

*The json is very big, that's why i don't want to use json_decode (php)*

Comment: Try `selectRaw` instead

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you very much, it works perfectly with ->selectRaw('data->"$[2]" as data')